# Azure Function Python docker container: Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-functions

I'm having trouble getting my Azure Function (python, timer trigger) to work in a docker container. Outside of the docker container, everything works just fine. But as soon as I start my container, I get an error saying:

> fail: Host.Startup[515] A host error has occurred
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding.

My connection string is defined in my local.settings.json. I have no clue as to why this isn't working in the docker container, has anyone dealt with this? I appreciate any direction, thank you.

Edit: Just a clarification, this is happening on my local machine. I have not deployed yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said before, I defined my connection string in my local.settings.json. I ended up accessing the file system of the container, and verified that my local.settings.json was in fact in there. I ended up adding my connection string as an env variable in my docker file (AzureWebJobsStorage={YOURCONNNECTIONSTRINGHERE}) and got it working. Hopefully this helps someone who comes across this issue.

Comment: Thank you for this. My error message was slightly different: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string 'Storage' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.` But the solution was the same. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

we can pass the connection string as an environment variable called *AzureWebJobsStorage* to the docker run command.

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -it -e AzureWebJobsStorage="{connection-string}" <docker-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is in this github issue.

Basically local.settings.json is only used by the local CLI, it's totally ignored by the runtime

Comment: You forgot to link the github issue

Comment: Oh this is more than 1.5 years, I don't think I can find the link now, but maybe a link to the documentation might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cmacos%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#local-settings